# Como alterar cor em html

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando alterar um trecho de codigo HTML para vermelho, mas o codigo abaixo não da certo. Achei q o color="red" funcionaria.
Obs: trata-se de html embutido em javascript. Quando eu removo o trecho da cor, ou seja, color="red", o codigo roda de boa.

```
var message = "RECOMENDAÇÃO DE AUDITORIA: " + dataRange[i][3] 
      + "<P> -------------------------------------------------</P>" 
      + "<P> *Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento da Crefiska, de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deve ser respondida até " + dataFim + ". Para esclarecimentos, consulta o manual e falar com o auditor " + dataRange[i][1]
      +"<HTML><BODY><i><font size=1 color="red"> A finalidade básica da medidas cabíveis (Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, de 02 de Dezembro de 2015)  </font></i></A>" 
      + "</BODY></HTML>";
```

Tenho um código javascript que le dados de uma planilha do google, e envia um alerta ´para um email quando o prazo expira. Esse alerta precisa ter um trecho em cor diferenciada, vermelho q eh o q eu estou tentando fazer. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, exceto que a cor nunca muda; sempre é exibida em preto. No código abaixo, eu quero que o destinatário receba o seguinte trecho em vermelho: "A finalidade básica da auditoria é controlar prazos. Esteja atento a eles". Ele ta recebendo, mas recebe preto. O código completo eh esse:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows


  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
     var expire = dataRange[i][8]; 

    if (expire < 10) {
      var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7];
      var subject = "Você tem um prazo de auditoria vencendo em " + dataRange[i][8] + " dias";
      //var teste = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][1], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var dataEnvio = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][0], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var dataFim = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][4], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var message = "RECOMENDAÇÃO DE AUDITORIA: " + dataRange[i][3] 
      + "<P> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</P>" 
      + "<P> *Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deve ser respondida até " + dataFim + ". Para esclarecimentos, consulta o manual de auditoria e monitoramento, disponível aqui; entrar em contato com a SESF, pelo telefone 123456 e falar com o auditor " + dataRange[i][1]
      +"<HTML><BODY><i><font size=1> A finalidade básica da auditoria é controlar prazos. Esteja atento a eles. </font></i></A>" 
      + "</BODY></HTML>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
   }

}
}
```

Comment: tenta com aspas simples color='red'

Answer (score 3):

O problema esta na hora de utilizar as aspas, se você quiser utilizar dentro da string a aspas você precisa colocar desta forma \", eu removi a tag font que não é mais usada, e utilizei style no lugar:

```
var message = "RECOMENDAÇÃO DE AUDITORIA: " + dataRange[i][3] 
      + "<P> -------------------------------------------------</P>" 
      + "<P> *Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento da Crefiska, de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deve ser respondida até " + dataFim + ". Para esclarecimentos, consulta o manual e falar com o auditor " + dataRange[i][1]
      +"<HTML><BODY><i style=\"color: red; font-size: 1px;\"> A finalidade básica da medidas cabíveis (Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, de 02 de Dezembro de 2015)</i></A>" 
      + "</BODY></HTML>";
```

Um exemplo simples para o texto ficar vermelho:

```js
//Executa a ação depois que a pagina foi totalmente carregada.
window.onload = function() {

  //Tag i com o texto e a coloração vermelha com fonte com o tamanho de 15px
  var texto = "<i style=\"color: red; font-size: 15px;\"> A finalidade básica da medidas cabíveis (Portaria PRESI 1144/2015, de 02 de Dezembro de 2015)</i>";
  
  //Seto dentro da div "meu_texto" a tag i
  document.getElementById("meu_texto").innerHTML = texto;

};
```

```html
<div id="meu_texto">
</div>
```

Tente enviar desta forma:

```
var message = "<P>RECOMENDAÇÃO DE AUDITORIA: " + dataRange[i][3] + "</P>"
      + "<P> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</P>" 
      + "<P>*Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento de " + dataEnvio + "\n" 
      + ", que deve ser respondida até " + dataFim + ". Para esclarecimentos, consulta o manual de auditoria e monitoramento, disponível aqui; entrar em contato com a SESF, pelo telefone 123456 e falar com o auditor " + dataRange[i][1] + "</P>"
      +"<P><i style='color: red;'> A finalidade básica da auditoria é controlar prazos. Esteja atento a eles.</i></P>";
```

Algumas tags foram removidas, como html e body, que não são necessárias neste exemplo.

Comment: Ou simplesmente passe os parâmetros do style para aspas simples.

Comment: Obrigado,mas não funcionou. A String é exibida em preto, e deveria ser vermelha. O seu exibiu vermelho? O q pode estar errado?

Comment: Aqui ficou vermelho, eu não sei o que você esta fazendo, mas a font com 1px não é muito pequena? Outra coisa, porque você esta usando as tags html e body para mostrar esta mensagem?

Comment: Continua preto. Eu apenas copiei um exemplo da net. Eu posso fazer diferente? Como? não entendo de html. Como estou embutindo html em javascript, resolvi criar um arquivo *.html apenas com o trecho abaixo, porem, os browsers continuam exibindo em preto.

Comment: O codigo do novo arquivo eh esse. Respondendo a outra pergunta, sim a fonte deve ser exatamente desse tamano, pois se trata apenas de uma nota explicativa q estou inserindo no rodape.             
<HTML><BODY><i style=\"color: red; font-size: 1px;\"> A finalidade básica da medidas cabíve </i></A></BODY></HTML>

Comment: Se você for usar o html diretamente, você não precisa colocar \" você tem que deixar o " diretamente.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? Qual é o objetivo do código?

Comment: Eu só quero que o trecho "A finalidade básica da medidas cabível" seja exibido em vermelho. Apenas isso. E não está sendo. Como e que codigo html eu vou usar, isso é irrelevante.

Comment: Digamos que seja para fins de estudo. Eu peguei esse codigo, salvei como teste.html, executei e continua exibindo em preto esse trecho q lhe falei. Logo, creio q o codigo não seja esse, q esteja faltando algo. Grato

Comment: Mas você quer logar ele em uma div? Ou é um alert?

Comment: fiz um exemplo simples, logando o texto vermelho dentro de uma div e coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Editei mais uma vez a pergunta, no final eu postei uma nova formatação para você tentar enviar.

Comment: Por favor, avalie a resposta e marque como respondida.